# How to compare string date to iso date format in a query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase

How can I query a collection where my startDate >= '01/01/2019'. The startDate is in iso Date (2019-01-12T10:02:16.387Z). This is my query:

```
const reservationRef = db.collection('reservation').startAt('2019-01-12T10:02:16.387Z')
```

Comment: `db.collection('reservation').startAt(new Date('2019-01-12T10:02:16.387Z'))`

Comment: I'd suggest storing your dates as timestamp type fields, which are easier to compare and require less space.

Comment: I tried your solution and it's not working. I don't have control over the database. I can't change the date's format

Comment: Can you explain what you mean. Why do you not have control over the database?

Comment: I can't change the date type on the database. I have to work with utc format

Answer (score 0):

Store all database dates and times as a timestamp. It's much easier to compare values that way. And it's also easier to present them on the UI if you use a timestamp.